# Difference between Event and Mutex in multi-threading

Tags: multithreading

I am just having a tough time to get the difference between Mutex and Event , can somebody point up the difference to me and show when to use each ?

Comment: What language are you talking about and what descriptions have you not understood?

Comment: i am coding with C++ language .i got that i use Mutex when i try to prevent 2 threads or more from writing on the same variable at the same time , so we could prevent wrong data.                                                                                 But when shall i use Event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to relate apples and oranges here.

A mutex is an object used to enforce mutual exclusion (hence the name "mut": "mutual", "ex": "exclusion"). In other words, to prevent two or more threads from accessing the same resource or group of resources at once.

In Java, any object can be used as a mutex. Typically mutexes are immutable objects and commonly are defined like so: `final Object mutex = new Object();`

In Java 5+ with the introduction of the `java.util.concurrent` package came more advanced forms of mutexes and other mechanisms for mutual exclusion.

Events are not a concept truly defined in Java. There are many different types and paradigms for events in programming. The Swing API defines an event paradigm. Google's Event Bus and [my similar implementation](https://github.com/Jire/samaritano/tree/master/samaritano/event) define another paradigm. These paradigms make an event have different meanings and uses.

If you could explain what you mean when referring to "event" it would help to further answer the question. Thank you!